# Redshift encryption and decrypted could not insert the data into redshift

Tags: encryption, amazon-redshift

I have applied Encryption function using aes_decrypt function in Redshift table.Now try to revert the data using aes_decrypt function.Could not update the data or insert to another table.

It Return errors like "error:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128). Please look at svl_udf_log for more information redshift"?

Comment: What do you see in `svl_udf_log` table?

Comment: It shows "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position"

Comment: It's hard for us to solve this with little info you provided

Comment: Sorry, It shows some message `"'UnicodeEncodeError: ''ascii'' codec can''t encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)'"'UnicodeEncodeError: ''ascii'' codec can''t encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)'
'UnicodeEncodeError: ''ascii'' codec can''t encode character u''\\xed'' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)'
'UnicodeEncodeError: ''ascii'' codec can''t encode character u''\\xf1'' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)'
`

Comment: "I have applied Encryption function using aes_decrypt function" -- do you mean _encrypt_ function?